# Deploy a Review app via the Platform API

Tags: heroku, heroku-api

Is there a way, via the Heroku Platform API (or any other Heroku API). To create/destroy a Review App?

Our configuration is set to not create review apps on every PR and I would like to be able to create a review app based on some signal in the PR's branch name.

Thanks.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Nicolas No, but I did get a Tumbleweed badge!

Comment: just stumbled onto this question: it seems like the [new version of the review apps also have an API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#review-apps-api)